# Finding coordinates for 'TRMM 3B42: 3-Hourly Precipitation Estimates' data covering region in Malawi

Tags: google-earth-engine, malawi

I have weekly precicipation data covering a certain region in Malawi.
The data is from google earth engine.

I would like to know the coordinates from the data was extracted.

The data was extracted using this script:

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('TRMM/3B42')
                  .filter(ee.Filter.date('2018-04-01', '2018-04-10'));
var precipitation =
    dataset.select(['precipitation', 'HQprecipitation', 'IRprecipitation']);
var precipitationVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 12.0,
  gamma: 5.0,
};
Map.setCenter(-79.98, 23.32, 4);
Map.addLayer(precipitation, precipitationVis, 'Precipitation');
```

Is there a way I can get the coordinates of this region?

Comment: @Erik that gives the centre but not the region. It's not helpful.

Comment: When I run that script I see the whole world, not Malawi. How have you get weekly data just for Malawi? Because that script doesn't seem to do that. In what form have you got the data?

Comment: @Spacedman 4 is the zoom level, with 1 being the whole planet, so you should be able to calculate the extent of the area.

Comment: @Erik in any case that's the zoom of the view, which is nothing to do with the data. I ran this code in Google Earth Engine. Did you? If the questioner has extracted data for Malawi only, then they're not telling us everything, in which case I've asked for clarification.